# numerical differentiation with the second derivative

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

derive the following differentiation formula

$$f''(0)=f(-1)-2f(0)+f(1) $$

a) using interpolation

b) using method of undetermined coefficients

c) find an upper bound for the error $\lvert e''(0)\rvert$

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually i haven't because i couldn't understand the basis of the this subject

Comment: [More accurate formula derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2215415/155436).

Comment: this one is useful, thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$f (1)\approx f (0)+f'(0)+\frac{f''(0)}{2}$$

$$f (-1)\approx f (0)-f (0)+\frac {f''(0)}{2} $$

by sum, we find

$$f (1)+f (-1)=2f (0)+f''(0) $$

Answer (score 2):

### Taylor series expansion

$$
 f(x) = f\left(x_{0} \right) + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\left(x-x_{0}\right)^{k}}{k!}f^{k}(x_{0})
$$

---

Look right:
$$
f'(x_{0} \color{blue}{+} h) = f\left(x_{0} \right) \color{blue}{+} 
f'\left(x_{0} \right) h +
f''\left(x_{0} \right) \frac{h^{2}}{2!} \color{blue}{+} 
f'''\left(x_{0} \right) \frac{h^{3}}{3!} + \dots
\tag{1}
$$

Look left:
$$
f'(x_{0} \color{red}{-} h) = f\left(x_{0} \right) \color{red}{-} 
f'\left(x_{0} \right) h +
f''\left(x_{0} \right) \frac{h^{2}}{2!}\color{red}{-} 
f'''\left(x_{0} \right) \frac{h^{3}}{3!} + \dots
\tag{2}
$$

---

### Centered difference approximations

$(1) \color{red}{-} (2)$
$$
  f'(x_{0}) = \frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)}{2h} + \mathcal{O}\left( h^{2} \right)
\tag{3}
$$

$(1) \color{blue}{+} (2)$
$$
  f''(x_{0}) = \frac{f(x_{0} - h) - 2f(x_{0}) + f(x_{0} + h)}{h^{2}} + \mathcal{O}\left( h^{2} \right)
\tag{4}
$$

The stated question is in the form $(4)$ with the assignments
$$
 x_{0} = 0, \quad h = 1
$$

### Forward and backward differences

Rearrange $(1)$ for the *forward difference approximation*
$$
 f'_{R}(x_{0}) = \frac{f(x_{0}+h) - f(x_{0})}{h} + \mathcal{O}\left( h \right)
\tag{5}
$$
Rearrange $(2)$ for the *backward difference approximation*
$$
 f'_{L}(x_{0}) = \frac{f(x_{0}) - f(x_{0}-h)}{h} + \mathcal{O}\left( h \right)
\tag{6}
$$
Derive $(4)$ from $(5)$ and $(6)$
$$
\begin{align}
%
f''(x_{0}) &= \left( f'(x_{0}) \right)' \\
  &=
\left( \frac{f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0} - h)}{h} \right)' \\
  &= 
%
  \frac{f'_{R}(x_{0}) - f'_{L}(x_{0})}{h} \\
%
  &= 
\frac{
\frac{f(x_{0}+h) - f(x_{0})}{h} - 
\frac{f(x_{0}) - f(x_{0}-h)}{h}}
{h} \\
%
 & = \frac{f(x_{0} - h) - 2f(x_{0}) + f(x_{0} + h)}{h^{2}} 
%
\end{align}
$$

### Error bound

The truncation error in $(1)$ and $(2)$ is majorized by 
$$
M \frac{h^{2}}{3!}
$$